# How to construct a cross-validation object manually in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, class, cross-validation

I have a kind of specific dataset in which several observations (each represented by a separate row) belong to the same object of investigation (e.g. measurements of the same object were performed several times). Each object (and observation) belongs to a certain class. The **problem** is this: it's needed a CV object in which observations are divided partitions and all observations of the same object  belong to the same (either training or validation) partition as a block of data. Unfortunately I'm not sure how to implement this. 
 I  tried to change indices in CV object (cvo), but it seems that the access to some properties such as indices (e.g., cvo.indices) is forbidden.

Comment: I found, that I can modify the cross-validation object (CVO) which class is _cvpartition_ by modifying several lines in _cvpartition.m_ file from:

`properties(GetAccess = 'private', SetAccess = 'private')`

to:

`properties(GetAccess = 'public', SetAccess = 'public')`

This allowed me to modify indices of CVO manually.

I wonder if there are any other way to set indices of CVO without changing the lines in _cvpartition.m_? This is the case when I want to run Matlab on my campus computer.